# hwi_oauth can't connect to FOS_OAUTH_SERVER

Tags: oauth-2.0, hwioauthbundle, fosoauthserverbundle, symfony-4.2

I looked through several solutions with the centralised login service.

My Situation is as following:

- Central Login under login.domain.tld
- Backend under backend.domain.tld
- Customer Service under: support.domain.tld
- frontend under frontend.domain.tld
- account and invoices under accounts.domain.tld

I set up the friends of Symfony oauth server with the correct routing as mentioned in the configs including tables etc.

I also added and oauth login token etc. for backend.domain.tld

as far as I could see, everything is setup the way it is ment to be. (not that much to be configured)

On the Backend I installed hwi_oauth bundle in Version 0.6.x

These are the configuration files:

httplug.yaml:

```
    httplug:
        plugins:
            redirect:
                preserve_header: true
        discovery:
            client: 'auto'
        clients:
            default:
                factory: 'httplug.factory.curl'
            app:
                http_methods_client: true
                plugins:
                    - 'httplug.plugin.content_length'
                    - 'httplug.plugin.redirect'
            hwi_special:
                factory: 'httplug.factory.guzzle6'
                config: # You pass here the Guzzle configuration, exactly like before.
                    timeout: 10
                    verify: false
                    max_redirects: 1
                    ignore_errors: false
```

HWI_oauth.yaml

```
    hwi_oauth:
        http:
            client: httplug.client.hwi_special
        firewall_names: [ main ]
        resource_owners:
            domain_oauth:
                type: oauth2
                client_id: '%env(OAUTH_CLIENT_ID)%'
                client_secret: '%env(OAUTH_CLIENT_TOKEN)%'
                access_token_url: '%env(OAUTH_PROVIDER)%'
                authorization_url: '%env(OAUTH_AUTHORISATION)%'
                options:
                    csrf: true
                infos_url:           '%env(OAUTH_USERINFO)%'
                scope:               "read"
                user_response_class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse
                paths:
                    identifier: id
                    nickname:   username
                    realname:   fullname
```

the env files are required as I need to replace dev system urls (xxx.domain.test with its productive counterpart)

the security.yaml

```
security:
  access_control:
    - path: ^/login
      roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ]
      requires_channel: https
    - path: ^/
      roles: ROLE_STAFF
      requires_channel: https
  providers:
    domain_provider:
      entity:
        class: Domain\Library\EntitiesBundle\Entities\User\User
        property: email
  # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
  # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: ~
      oauth:
        resource_owners:
          domain_oauth: "/login/domainLogin"
        login_path: "/login"
        use_forward: true
        failure_path: "/login"

        oauth_user_provider:
          service: Domain\Library\ClientAuthBundle\Authorisation\HwiOAuthProvider
  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_GUEST:
    ROLE_USER: [ ROLE_GUEST ]
    ROLE_STAFF: [ ROLE_USER ]
```

The Bundle Domain\Library\EntitiesBundle\Entities\User\User is an private Bundle the contains all Migration Data and Entity Tables.

and last but not least the twi_oauth_routing.yaml

```
    # app/config/routing.yml
    hwi_oauth_redirect:
        resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect_41.xml"
        prefix:   /connect

    hwi_oauth_connect:
        resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect_41.xml"
        prefix:   /connect

    hwi_oauth_login:
        resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login_41.xml"
        prefix:   /login

    domain_oauth_login:
        path: /login/domainLogin
```

The Difficulty that I'm currently facing is, that I can't see an connection attempt on the login system when I call backend.domain.test/login
I see an link that points to /connect/domain-oauth (which I never configured anywhere).
If I click on that, it redirects me to /login
But I don't see an connection in the logs.

Any clues what I oversaw?
I am trying to get this to work for about a week.
Worked through several examples but I can't get it to work properly.

Any Help is appreciated.

Software: Symfony 4.2, PHP7.3 MySQL 8, Redis as Cache

---

Update: I was able to get it to work so far.
I was missing an access_control rule for the path to /connect/.... path.

Now I can see an allow / deny buttons.

But as soon as I cluck allow I get in the profiler the following url bevor it is redirected to the login page:

https://baclend.domain.tld/login/domainLogin?error=invalid_scope&error_description=An%20unsupported%20scope%20was%20requested.&state=51057e2ba6bd1540e5981e193c24ac9c

What did I miss out?
I don't know what this error is trying to tell me.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: During creation of the client in fos Oauth Server I missed to add an additional scope for authorisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved.

Issues where related to problems in the firewall settings and due to an missing scope for authorisation.